# Re-initialize iTunes track while keeping iTunes metadata?

Tags: itunes, music, ipod, playlist

**Background:**

I have been having the issue described here:

- [Why does my iPod Classic cut off the end of certain songs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/38788/151730)

Except, it's not an iPod Classic.  It's a brand new iPod Nano 7th Generation, and a brand new MacBook Pro running macOS El Capitan 10.11.6.

The iTunes library was copied from my old 2011 MacBook Pro running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4.

The "skip to the end" issue has been plaguing me for years, with odd little quirks:

- Songs played on my 4th Generation iPod Touch never skip to the end.
- Songs played on my 10.7.4 MBP sometimes skip to the end.

  It is reproducible—if a song skips to the end, I can play that song over and over again, and it will skip to the end every time.  But there is no evident pattern to which songs skip to the end and which don't.

  It is also possible to work around: If I drag the playback slider just past the skip point, I can play the rest of the song.  (Great workaround.  Ugh.)
- Songs played on my 10.11.6 MBP exhibit the same behavior as on my 10.7.4 MBP.
- Songs played on my 7th Gen iPod Nano skip to the end, but unlike in iTunes, the length of the song is actually falsely shown to be the truncated length.

  For example, the Red Hot Chili Peppers song, "Under the Bridge" has a duration of 4:26 and is shown as such in iTunes.  However, when playback reaches 1:37, the song skips to the end and the next song starts playing.  On my 7th Gen iPod Nano, the duration of this song is shown as 1:37 and there is *no* workaround by which I can listen to the remainder of the song.
- Setting the "stop position" for the song (which I do *not* have set for any of the affected songs in my library) does not appear to affect this behavior.
- **When a song is removed from iTunes and re-added, the behavior goes away for *that* song.**

Which brings me to my question:

**Can I "re-initialize" a track in iTunes while keeping the metadata?**  In other words, can I simulate removing and re-adding the file while preserving at least:

- song rating
- play count
- inclusion (and position) in playlists
- date added

Comment: It may be worth noting that this *single* issue may be enough of a problem to drive me entirely away from iTunes.  It is, after all, a showstopper: A user can't play music using his music player.  But I do love the iTunes interface, so I'm hoping it can be fixed.

Comment: Could try this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77193/is-there-a-way-to-force-itunes-11-to-update-tags/103445